# Domain Driven Design in Python: Prevent recursive bidirectional relationship in data mappers

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, sqlalchemy, domain-driven-design

In the ExerciseModel file I have the following mapper to an Exercise entity:

```
def to_entity(self):
        return Exercise(
            id=self.id,
            questionURL=self.questionURL,
            answerURL=self.answerURL,
            option1=self.option1,
            option2=self.option2,
            option3=self.option3,
            option4=self.option4,
            difficulty=self.difficulty,
            exercisegroup=self.exercisegroup.to_entity() if self.exercisegroup else None,
            exercise_playlists=[exercise_playlist.to_entity() for exercise_playlist in self.exercise_playlists] if self.exercise_playlists else None,
            studentanswers=[studentanswer.to_entity() for studentanswer in self.studentanswers] if self.studentanswers else None
        )
```

In the ExerciseGroupModel file I have the mapper to ExerciseGroup entity as follows:

```
def to_entity(self):
        return ExerciseGroup(
            id=self.id,
            name=self.name,
            schoolyear=self.schoolyear,
            subject=self.subject.to_entity() if self.subject else None,
            exercises=[exercise.to_entity() for exercise in self.exercises] if self.exercises else None
        )
```

The problem arrises when I call the ExerciseModel.to_entity(), which in turn calls the ExerciseGroupModel.to_entity() which calls the ExerciseModel.to_entity(), entering an infinite recursive cycle.

I tried to only store the exercise group ID and then making a query to the DB to convert de exercisegroup from id to model, but I don't think that's the standard way of doing it. I also tried to include optional arguments in the to_entity() method, like `to_entity(self, existing_exercise_group = None, ...)`, finding a way not to call the ExerciseGroupModel to entity.

Comment: in general, you sould make sure the recursive function exits with some condition...  in yhe case of  the question, presumably a counter variable would be suitable.